# KVM iptables VM connect using host IP

Tags: iptables, kvm-virtualization

I have three VMs on a host:

```
Hardware Host:  192.168.0.220
  VM-1:  192.168.122.10
  VM-2:  192.168.122.11
  VM-3:  192.168.122.12
```

I can connect from one VM to the other using the VM's IP address (e.g. `telnet 192.168.122.11 3306` works to connect from VM-3 to VM-2).

I want to connect to the VMs using the host IP, like:  `telnet 192.168.0.220 3306` from VM-3 to connect to VM-2.  What iptables entries are needed on the host?

Comment: what you want is port forwarding with hairpinning - see [this](https://superuser.com/questions/995986/hairpinning-in-linux)